# xConnect upgrade issues (upgrade from Sitecore 9.0.1 to 9.0.2)

Tags: upgrade, xconnect

I am trying to upgrade a solution from Sitecore 9.0.1 to Sitecore 9.0.2
The upgrade package went well, followed the procedure upgraded xConnect as well.

When trying to work with list manager - do not see any of my contacts.

In sitecore log there is exception

```
11896 13:39:53 ERROR [ListManagement]: Failed to get count of contacts for 60287a84-243b-4946-a51c-31366baf3842 contact list. The error has been occurred: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.GetBatchEnumeratorSync[TEntity](IAsyncQueryable`1 asyncQueryable, Int32 defaultBatchSize)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.SegmentationEngine.c.b__24_0(IAsyncQueryable`1 contacts)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.SegmentationEngine.PerformSearch[T](IContactSearchQueryFactory queryFactory, Func`2 searchWork, Byte[] syncToken, ContactExpandOptions expandOptions)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.SegmentationEngine.CountContacts(IContactSearchQueryFactory queryFactory)
   at Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.Repositories.ListRepositoryBase`1.c__DisplayClass51_0.b__0()

14112 13:39:53 ERROR [ListManagement]: Failed to get count of contacts for 88184756-e227-4d0c-b816-ee71ab4c843f contact list. The error has been occurred: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
```

And in xConnect logs I see next:

```
2018-07-13 14:43:20.437 +02:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.InvalidOperationException: Cursor functionality requires a sort containing a uniqueKey field tie breaker
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.MoveReaderToResponse(JsonTextReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.ParseSearchResponse[TSolrResult](JsonTextReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonResultsParser.d__3`1.MoveNext()
```

Any ideas what is missing?

I did update all solr cores with uniqueId field change as described in the upgrade guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that `xdb` and `xdb_rebuild` cores should not be updated with manages schema `uniqueId` fields. However the upgrade guilde says all cores should be updated. So resolution was rolling back managed schemas for xdb SOLR cores.